# How to customise a the size of the Master is the SPlitviewcontroller?

Tags: ipad, resize, uisplitviewcontroller

My master view is a typical table view. But, the cell content is just to the max 5 letters. I wanted to resize the master in my splitview. Is there a way for us to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the width of Master in UISplitViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

The docs state "The first pane of a split view controller has a fixed width of 320 points and a height that matches the visible window height. The second pane fills the remaining space.", so it doesn't appear that you can.  I'd suggest filing a Radar enhancement request.