# How do you create a slide out tableView on the right instead of the left of iPad Master-Detail Application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

If you create an iPad Master-Detail Application and use Portrait orientation, it gives you a slide out tableView on the left.
1. How do you make it to show on the right?

Also, in the landscape orientation, it is split in into two views.

1. How do you make it so that it will be the same as the Portrait View, like slide the TableView out?
2. Is it possible to adjust the size of the Detail View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want two views in landscape, why do you need a splitView at all? You can just have a UIView with a popover button on the top bar. Then you can add the tableviewcontroller to the popover. To show it to the right you can define the rect or use the rightbarbuttonitem to add the popover.

Answer (score 0):

You can have master on right by passing masterviewcontroller as second parameter to the array assigned to splitViewController.viewcontroller. However, you cannot resize the master and detail views. Hence you will end up having a bigger masterView than the detailview.

Looking at limited functionality of UISplitViewController, it may not be possible to have master on right(properly working as per your requirements). You can have your own controller to get this done or try using opensource options like [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/08/03/mgsplitviewcontroller-updated/).

you may also like to look into this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller/4017908#4017908)