# SplitViewController for iPad behaviors

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, cell

I am working with the UISplitViewController in iPad application.
Currently, I found two issues:
1. I can't modify the width of the master view
2. I try to use the customized cell in the master view, but it seems not possible to adjust the width and height of the cell.

Do you have any ideas on the two issues regarding to the standard UISplitViewController?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: you can change the height of the cell, because I have already done it in my project. Can you please explain what did you do to change the height?

Comment: I just use my custom table cell(with customized cell, e.g. height 60) in the master. In the master table, I set the cell with the same height. However, no changes in the UI as I expected.

Comment: For the 1st question, I just noticed that there is a 3rd party library, https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController    Do you have any ideas that it can work?

Comment: Please use the heightForRowAtIndex delegate method. return 60 from that method.

Comment: That's it. The right way to adjust the height of the customized cell. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You cannot change the size of detail view.
Please check the following link, From that link you will get alot of information:
[Change the width of Master in UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller)

2) Use the heightForRowAtIndex delegate method. return 60 from that method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   return 60.0;
 }
```