# Refresh UISplitViewController after changing the Master's width

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using iOS 6.0. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller), I know I could use

```
[splitViewController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
```

To change the width of master view.(I do not need to upload my app to AppStore).

But I found this only works in my **AppDelegate**, before

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

For example, it does not work in my **MasterViewController**  **viewDidLoad** method

I guessed it is because the **splieViewController** does not reloadView after changing this "_masterColumnWidth" property. What should I do next if I want to change the Master Column width in **MasterViewController**?

Could you please throw some light on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crashes now under iOS 10, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26057825/2270880 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
[splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
```

I use it to show/hide the MasterViewContoller in landscape mode.