# How to implement xcode storyboard with left side menu (without slide)?

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard

I tried to search on this website but I don't found what I want.

I'm developing my first iPad app with Xcode (iOS 7) and I'd like to put a list always displayed at the left and when clicking on some elements of the list the view controller has to changed.

Should I use a masterDetail ? Or something Else?

How can represent that in the storyboard?

Thanks

[Picture here](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/751x447q90/59/n8zd.png)

Comment: If master detail does what you want then yes. How should your app react on rotation?

Comment: My app is only available in landscape! But can we adjust each parts (master, details) about width size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the master detail template. This will create for you a `UISplitView` with a list on the left and detail view on the right. You can then adjust the code to your needs.

Comment: Can we adjust each parts (master, details) about width size?

Comment: Not when using the default split view. Check, foe example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller