# How to change width sizes of split view controller items (Master View Controller - Detail View Controller)?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I need to change width sizes of View Controllers in Split View Controller. I mean the default value of first view controller is 320. Second one is 703. I need to change them with 605 and 419. Btw project is iPad - Landscape project. So is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Please refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller/42803037#42803037](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller/42803037#42803037)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class `UISplitViewController` exposes a property to change the width of the master view. This property is `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction` with which you can specify the width of the master view as a percentage respect the total width of the split view.

Comment: Thank you. Should I use this property on SplitViewController.swift or DetailViewController.swift or MasterViewController.swift ?

Comment: This is a property of the SplitViewController. You have to define it when you create the SplitViewController.