# Update frame of DetailViewController in subclass of UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I wish to change the frame of `DetailViewController` when `splitViewController?.displayMode == .PrimaryOverlay`, such that the `DetailViewController` view is never obscured by the `MasterViewController`. I have managed to get this working when navigating from `splitViewController?.displayMode == .PrimaryHidden` to `splitViewController?.displayMode == .PrimaryOverlay` in iPad portrait orientation, using a custom UISplitViewController with overriden `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method as described in jrc's answer here: [Change the width of Master in UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949067/change-the-width-of-master-in-uisplitviewcontroller) (see below). I have linked the UISplitViewController in storyboard to `SplitViewController`, and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called on initial app load with iPad.

**SplitViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        var masterViewController = (self.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController
        var detailViewController = (self.viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController

        // Adjust the width of the detail view
        var detailViewFrame = detailViewController!.view.frame
        detailViewFrame.origin.x += masterViewController!.view.frame.width
        detailViewFrame.size.width -= masterViewController!.view.frame.width
        detailViewController!.view.frame = detailViewFrame

        detailViewController!.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }
```

However, when I am in `splitViewController?.displayMode == .PrimaryOverlay`, and subsequently select a different item from `MasterViewController`, the DetailViewController frame reverts back to the default frame size and position. I have tried to fix this using the following (although calling `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in this way is not recommended):

**MasterViewController.swift**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        collapseDetailViewController = false
        splitViewController?.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
```

Now when I select an item in `MasterViewController.swift` `splitViewController?.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is being called, but I get strange readings when printing the DetailViewController's `view.frame.origin.x` and `view.frame.width` at the end of `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. And even with these changes to the frame which seem to have been made, the `DetailViewController` view is still being obscured.

Would appreciate if some help on how to fix the `DetailViewController` frame so that it is never obscured even when selecting new items in a `MasterViewController`. I have not had luck implementing any `UISplitViewController` delegate methods for solving this, and I also tried reloading the `SplitViewController` with `loadView` at the end of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but this caused a freeze of the iPad screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who wanted to know how to get the master and detail view controllers to go side by side without overlay when going onto an iPad, it's really easy! Just add `preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible`. No need to use custom SplitViewControllers like `MGSplitViewController` or alter the frame of the Split View Controller. :-)